# How to add faker data in django in place of foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

All I need is that user field of Product com from the foreign key of User model How can I add daker data here it gives me this error.

```
 Product.objects.create(
            Product_name=fake.name(),
            Product_desc = fake.text(),
            Price=fake.random_int(3000, 10000),
            user=1
        )
```

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    Product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Product_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    Price = models.IntegerField()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='set_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Product_name
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tmkR.png)

Comment: Please paste the error as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error makes complete sense, you can't assign `user=1` directly while creating instance, it must be `User` model instance so:

```py
Product.objects.create(
            Product_name=fake.name(),
            Product_desc = fake.text(),
            Price=fake.random_int(3000, 10000),
            user=get_object_or_404(User, id=1)
        )
```